# how to show modal from another file in to my html using laravel ajax

Tags: html, css, ajax, laravel, modal-dialog

i use Laravel and ajax,
in index.blade.php i have :

```
<a onclick="addForm()" class="btn btn-success " style="float:right;">Tambah</a>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addForm(){
        save_method = "add" ;
        $('input[name=method]').val('POST') ;
        $('#myModal').modal('show') ;
        $('#myModal form')[0].reset() ;
        $('.modal-title').text('Tambah Kategori') ;
    }
</script>
```

and i want call modal from another file called form.blade.php in the same folder with index.blade.php, this is my form :

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">

        <form class="form-horizontal" data-toggle="validator" method="POST">
            {{ csrf_field() }} {{ method_field('POST') }}

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>

                <h3 class="modal-title"></h3>

            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nama" class="col-md-3 control-label">Nama</label>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" id="nama" class="form-control" name="nama" autofocus required>
                        <span class="help-block with-errors"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-save">Simpan</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Batal</button>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

Why my modal didn't show?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include your `form.blade.php` file in your `index.blade.php` because your javascript has no reference to that file.

Doing this is explained in the blade documentation of laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#including-sub-views